# Strange assigned owner of docker mounted volume

Tags: docker, conan

I am on a remote server where I am a user in the group docker. I created two volumes:
`docker create volume conan` && docker create volume code`

I am using the docker image called conanio/gcc10, so I run:

```
docker run --rm \
    -v code:/home/conan/.code \
    -v conan:/home/conan/.conan \
    -it conanio/gcc10 /bin/bash
```

Then in the container environment I have:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 conan 1001 4096 Jun 23 01:58 .conan/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root 4096 Jun 23 01:58 .code/
```

why they have different owner? .code's owner is root and .conan's owner is conan?
I tried different names and all are the same, only .conan's owner is conan.
I also tried other images as well. Is that because the conan volume matches the user name in the container???

is there a way to use conan for other mounted volume as well?

Comment: check the ownership of the "code" folder in host system.

Comment: First, read the code: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-docker-tools/blob/master/gcc_10/Dockerfile. All images use 1001 as group id for conan folder. It's a workaround to allow volumes and write permission at same time.

Comment: Is there a way to mount the volume to be writable when in container?